# anuglar js: ng-repeat doesn't displaying anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm not really a js guy but i tried to show something with the ng-repeat in angular. But it doesn't display anything.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list-block" ng-controller="ContactController as acontact">
<ul>
   <li class="item-content" ng-repeat="customer in acontact.customers"product>
       <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
       <div class="item-inner">
           <div class="item-title">contact: {{ customer[0].Name }}</div>
           <div class="item-after">Label</div>
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('contact', []);

app.controller('ContactController', function($scope){
    var customers = myContext.customer.toArray();

    $.when(customers).then(function(customers) {
        $scope.customers = customers;
    }); 
});
```

**Debug**
I tried to find error out with the debug chrome extension:
[image: DebugAngular Scope Image]
[image: Customer in Console.log()]

This Image i can see for 1 sec and then it goes away and only the title stays there.
[image: 1 sec]

Maybe somebody know what i'm doing wrong?
Best Regards

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha myContext comes from JayData

Comment: @DavinTryon acontact is `<div class="list-block" ng-controller="ContactController as acontact">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the above answers, as far as customer is an object and not an array.
But maybe try accessing the name with:

```
customer.initData.Name
```

i.e.

```
<li class="item-content" ng-repeat="customer in customers"product>
    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
    <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title">contact: {{ customer.initData.Name }}</div>
        <div class="item-after">Label</div>
     </div>
</li>
```

and because you attached customers to $scope, here:

```
 $.when(customers).then(function(customers) {
        $scope.customers = customers;
    });
```

It means you dont have to reference the controller object, 
<s>ng-repeat="customer in acontact.customers"</s>
Try just using

```
ng-repeat="customer in customers"
```

Comment: yes i attacht it to an outer div i updated the `html code` but it also doesn't work with `customer.initData.Name`

Answer (score 1):

Your customer variable is not an array, it is already one of the customers. Try with `contact: {{ customer.Name }}` and all should be good.

Comment: still doesnt work :( I tried it with customer[0] because i thought like that i have to go in the initData object or array or whatever this is..

Comment: Int he picture you have posted there don't seem to be any Name parameter, try it with customer.Address and see if that works

Comment: Why are you iterating through acontact.customers in your ng-repeat instead of just customers? Shouldn't it be ng-repeat="customer in customers"? Try it like this ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe becouse of the $scope?, when you use it you can't use alias "as" in youre controller...

Comment: this question was asked 2 years ago and already has an accepted answer..